# Single-Ended Op-Amp

Tags: mosfet

[image]

For part A: Consider an increase in the voltage at Vi1 while Vi2 goes down by the same amount This will cause Iss(M7) in this case to push more current to the M1 side while the M2 side current decreases. If the M2 current decreases, less voltage drop across the load M4 and thus, higher voltage at A.

Here's where it get's confusing. This higher voltage at A get's passed to the input of the PMOS common-source stage with NMOS current source load. I know that a common-source stage has an inverting gain, so the higher input at A, should cause output voltage to go lower.

**So Vi1 is inverting input and hence Vi2 is the non-inverting input. Is that correct?**

For Part B: It's just the multiplicaiton of the gain of the two stages
$$A_v=-g_{m2}(r_{o4}||r_{o2})g_{m6}(r_{o5}||r_{o6})$$

For Part C: This is where I have no idea what to even look at it? Any ideas what it means? How much output swings if what?

Answer (score 1):

*So Vi1 is inverting input and hence Vi2 is the non-inverting input. Is that correct?*

Yes that is correct. I would reason as follows:

if Vi1 increases, Id(M1) increases. That increases Id(M3) and (it is a mirror) Id(M4).

So M4 will pull **up** the voltage at A. That then **decreases** the Vgs of M5. That will make Id(M5) decrease so the voltage at B will go **down**

A Voltage Increase at Vi1 => voltage decrease at B: Vi1 is the **inverting** input.

The small signal gain is indeed the multiplication of the two.

For the output voltage swing, it is not entirely clear what is asked.

If the output voltage swing is the voltage range that the output can reach, even when the amplifier is not behaving in a linear way, then we can just consider what the output voltage will be when we apply a very large input voltage difference. Then either M5 is off, M6 fully on (triode mode) or M5 fully on and M6 off. Then the output can reach VDD and ground voltage.

If the output voltage swing is the range for which the circuit operates in a **linear** way, meaning the input signal is still being converted into an output current then M5 and M6 will have to stay in saturation mode. Then the output voltage range is VDD - Vds,sat(M5) and Vds,sat(M6).